# "Unable to write in the cache directory" (Symfony)

Tags: php, apache, caching, permissions, symfony-3.4

I am trying to deploy my symfony 3.4 application into a production environment and after all configuration this error occurs when I access the index page:

```
[Thu Aug 30 15:46:27.245613 2018] [php7:error] [pid 1748]  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to write in the cache directory ([...]/app/cache/prod)
 in [...]/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:755
 Stack trace:
 #0 [...]/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(633): Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel->buildContainer()
 #1 [...]/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(137): Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel->initializeContainer()
 #2 [...]/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(197): Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel->boot()
 #3 [...]/web/app.php(14): Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request))
 #4 {main}
 thrown in [...]/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php on line 755
```

The app/cache and app/logs directories have the right permissions and they own to the "apache" user (Centos 7 server).

So, I don't know what I am doing wrong. What could be the solution?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, you would recommend to read this [guide for Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify your question in order to help users to understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your response MoxGeek. After many headaches I SOLVED it. The problem was not in the permissions but in the server configuration. I created a Centos 7 server instance with SELinux, so the problem was there.

The solution is just to disable SELinux. No more problems after that!
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

do you gives the right permission to your app/cache  and app/logs ? 
also don't forget to clear cache

Comment: Yes, I gave read an write permissions to app/cache and app/logs and I set that permissions for the apache user using ACL, so apache has the right permissions for those directories. I cleared cache too, but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This solution is working fine.

**Procedure:**

Open the SELinux configuration file: `/etc/selinux/config`
Locate the following line:

```
SELINUX=enforcing
```

Change the value to disabled:

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

Save your changes and close the file.
On the next reboot, SELinux is permanently disabled.

Note: Instead of disabling SELinux, you can also set `permissive` attribute. This will helps you to print warnings instead of `enforcing`.

Command:

```
SELINUX=permissive
```

To dynamically disable it before the reboot, run the following command:

```
# setenforce 0
```